# Make a method that contains a linear search?

Tags: c#, methods, linear-search

I'm new to programmning and I'm taking a course to learn the basics in c#.
Right now I'm doing a console application that are supposed to work as a blog. In the application the user should be able to write a new post, show written posts and search for written posts. The application is supposed to be a list that contains arrays.

I'm almost finished with the application but I want to make a method for the linear search that searches for the written blogposts but I cant get it to work.
Here's the code for the linear search:

```
case 3:
    Console.Write("Write the title for the post you are searching for: ");
    string searchedWord = Console.ReadLine();
    bool search = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < myBlog.Count; i++)
    {
        if (searchedWord.ToUpper() == myBlog[i][0].ToUpper())
        {
             search = true;                        
             Console.WriteLine("\nHe post you are looking for exists in the blog:");
             Console.WriteLine("\nTitle: " + myBlog[i][0] +
                               "\nPost: " + myBlog[i][1] +
                               "\n\nPress enter to return to the menu...");
        }

     }
     if (search == false)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("The searched word wasn't found. Press enter to return to the menu...");
     }
     break;
```

I made a try creating a method for it but I'm doing wrong, can somebody please tell me how to do it?

```
static string BlogSearch(List<string[]> myBlog, string searchedWord)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < myBlog; i++)
     {
          if (searchedWord.ToUpper() == myBlog[i][0].ToUpper())
                    return i;
     }
     return -1;
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work". How does it not work? Does it not compile? Does it not find anything? Does it throw an exception? Does it exhibit behavior different from what you'd expect? Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Unrelated: `if (searchedWord.ToUpper() == myBlog[i][0].ToUpper())` that won't always fly. better use [string.Equals(String, StringComparison)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=net-7.0#system-string-equals(system-string-system-stringcomparison)) with `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: You are also using `==` which means it needs to be an **exact** match on the complete title. I would recommend to _at least_ use [`Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-7.0) (if not even look for an easy implementation of a fuzzy search).

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < myBlog; i++)` -> `myBlog` is a `List<string[]>` so that needs to be `for (int i = 0; i < myBlog.Count; i++)`

Comment: Instead of using `List<string[]>` to store your blogs, I would suggest introducing a custom class, like a `BlogEntry`, with properties for things like Title, body, etc. Since it easier to read and understand `myBlogs[i].Title` than `myBlog[i][0]`.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are allowed to use Linq**, you can do

```
using System.Linq;
//....

static string[] BlogSearch(List<string[]> myBlog, string searchedWord)
{
    // "give me from myBlog ...
    //  the first element, that fits the criteria OR
    //  default if such an element is not in the list"
    return myBlog.FirstOrDefault(x => x[0].Contains(searchedWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```

See it in action in a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/avth62)

Mind that this returns `default(string)` (which is `null`) if the `searchedWord` is not found.

I guess you are using `string[]` because your class (pun intended) has not come across the concept of `class`es, yet. So I won't go into that. Just so much: usually, you would model your blog data into a class with specific properties. And later on, you would probably want to keep the data in a Database instead of memory ... but all that is not *really* related to the problem at hand.

**If you are NOT allowed to use Linq:**

```
static string[] BlogSearch(List<string[]> myBlog, string searchedWord)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < myBlog.Count; i++ )
    {
        if( myBlog[i][0].Contains(searchedWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return myBlog[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which is basically the same as the Linq version just coded out explicitly.

See it in action in a [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WLNVac).

---

### Usage

```
// ... case 3: ...
var result = BlogSearch(myBlog, searchedWord);
if( result is null )
{
    Console.WriteLine("The searched word wasn't found. Press enter to return to the menu...");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe post you are looking for exists in the blog:");
    Console.WriteLine("\nTitle: " + result[0] +
                      "\nPost: " + result[1] +
                      "\n\nPress enter to return to the menu...");
}
break;
```

---

Some hints for you concerning *your* code:

```
       //    You expect to be returning `string`
       //    but all return statements return `int`.
       // vv What you actually need is `string[]`, though.
static string BlogSearch(List<string[]> myBlog, string searchedWord)
{
     //                  vv that's a `List<T>`, so you need `myBlog.Count` here
     for (int i = 0; i < myBlog; i++)
     {
          // Two caveats:
          // 1. _Exact_ match
          // 2. `ToUpper` does not always work correctly.
          //    It is advised to use overloads with `StringComparison` argument
          if (searchedWord.ToUpper() == myBlog[i][0].ToUpper())
                    return i;
     }
     return -1;
}
```

Comment: We haven't come across Linq so I tried it without and what you wrote worked:D

We have talked about classes but just briefly and this time we didn't need to use a class.

Comment: I was wrong, it won't work completely. When you search for a blogpost that exists, it works, but if you search for something that doesn't exist I get this:
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to check the result of this Function for null `var result = BlogSearch(...); if(result is null) { // nothing found }`

Comment: See "Usage" in edited answer. @sam_the_man

Comment: Thank you, that solved it!
Now I only have one last question and that is if I can use the same method to delete an element in the list. I tried it the same way as the search but put in "myBLog.RemoveAt(i);"
I then get the message "The name i does not exist in the current context". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should open a separate question for that. I am sure, we can figure it out.