# Use a method with a linear search to remove an element from a list?

Tags: c#

I have made a console application that is like a blog and the user can show all written posts, write posts, search posts and I want to implement the option to delete a specific blog post.
I made a method for searching for written blogposts and I was thinking that I could use that for deleting posts as well, but when I use RemoveAt(i); I get the message: " The name i does not exist in the current context".

Here is the method for the linear search:

```
static string[] BlogSearch(List<string[]> myBlog, string searchedWord)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < myBlog.Count; i++)
            {

                if (myBlog[i][0].ToUpper() == searchedWord.ToUpper())
                    return myBlog[i];
            }
            return null;
        }
```

And here is what I tried to do to be able to remove a blogpost:

```
case 4:
     Console.Write("Write the title of the post you want to delete: ");
     string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
     string[] postToDelete = BlogSearch(myBlog, userInput);

     if(postToDelete == null)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("The blogpost you wanted to delete wasn't found.");
     }
     else
     {
         myBlog.RemoveAt(i);
     }
     break;
```

What should I do?

Comment: To all answerers: This is a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75057422/982149).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you based your attempt on the outcome of this code from an [answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75057593/982149):

```
static string[] BlogSearch(List<string[]> myBlog, string searchedWord)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < myBlog.Count; i++ )
    {
        if( myBlog[i][0].Contains(searchedWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return myBlog[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So you could do a similar thing:

```
static bool BlogDelete(List<string[]> myBlog, string searchedWord)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < myBlog.Count; i++ )
    {
        if( myBlog[i][0].Contains(searchedWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            myBlog.RemoveAt(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or you could modify the first one to return just the index:

```
static int BlogSearch(List<string[]> myBlog, string searchedWord)
{
    for( int i = 0; i < myBlog.Count; i++ )
    {
        if( myBlog[i][0].Contains(searchedWord, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

-1 represents "not found", otherwise you can go on and use the result as the index into your array that points to the search result.

Comment: I tried the first alternative you suggested and it worked great!
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

`i` only exists inside your `BlogSearch()` method. (Actually, only inside your `for` loop. Learn about [Scope](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/variable-scopes-in-csharp#:%7E:text=In%20C%23%2C%20the%20Scope%20of,a%20loop%2C%20condition%2C%20etc.) if you don't understand why). You need to return it so you can see it in your case statement.

It would probably be better to make a new `FindBlogIndex()` method to do the search and index return, then you can call that from your `BlogSearch()` method too.

ps. Finding the index isn't really necessary, since `List<T>` already has a [Remove()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-7.0) method that will find a matching object itself.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest returning both `blog` (array, which you may want to show to user) and its `index` (which you have to pass to `RemoveAt`) in *one go* (note, that in your current code you do the search *twice*: first on `BlogSearch` and then on blog removing):

```
static (string[] blog, int index) BlogSearch(List<string[]> myBlog, 
                                             string searchedWord) {
    for (int i = 0; i < myBlog.Count; ++i)
        if (string.Equals(myBlog[i][0], 
                          searchedWord, 
                          StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            return (myBlog[i], i);

    return (null, -1);
}
```

Then you can put it as follow

```
case 4:
    Console.Write("Write the title of the post you want to delete: ");
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
  
    var postToDelete = BlogSearch(myBlog, userInput);

    if (postToDelete.index < 0)  
        Console.WriteLine("The blogpost you wanted to delete wasn't found.");
    else {
        myBlog.RemoveAt(postToDelete.index);

        // If you want to get blog itself, use `.blog`, e.g 
        Console.WriteLine("Deleted blog: ");
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", postToDelete.blog));
    }

    break;
```